# Python function result to be displayed on html

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to get a python function, which loads data from database.db to be visible on html page after webpage loaded. This runs to internal server error. Any ideas?

The python is the following:

```
@app.route('/search')
def search():
    with sql.connect("database.db") as con:
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute(""" SELECT * FROM list""")
        data = cur.fetchall()
        for row in data:
            print("1: ", row[0])
            print("2: ", row[1])
            print("3: ", row[2])
            print("4: ", row[3])
            print("5: ", row[4])
    return render_template("search.html", output=search())
    con.close()
```

The html is following:

```
{% extends "headers/header.html" %}
{% block body %}
<h1>Results</h1>
<p>{{ output }}</p>

</main>
</body>
</html>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: can you put debugger points in after each line to track the issue line?

Comment: you need to specify you problem because now you make us to debug your code instead of you

Comment: You call `search` in `search`. Looks like an endless recursion.

Comment: search here is a function that flask will be responsible for calling,

you shouldn't call it ,

if you want the results to be in the output variable,

assign ```output=list(data)```

and render it in the template.

Comment: also if you found the line of error you need to add to the question the exact error message

Comment: Hi sorry, it does not return any error code, just on the HTML it gives result "None". I had a typo on code and that's why it was giving an error in the first place.

Answer (score -4):

Connect it to a server at first using SQL or PHP my Admin then you can use your HTML and CSS to run the program itself